# onTouchEvent() not working as I intend

Tags: java, android, touch-event

Following: https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/movement.html

for handling movement in an `onTouchEvent`. My problem is though that it seems the touch is never registered, even when following the tutorial linked.

Code:

```
public class Sprite extends Activity {

private static final int BMP_ROWS = 4;
private static final int BMP_COL = 3;
private int x, y = 0;
private int speedx, speedy = 5;
private int currentFrame = 0;
private int width, height;
private float xTouch, yTouch;
private VelocityTracker mVelocityTracker = null;
private GameView gameView;
private Bitmap bmp;

int [] DIRECTION_TO_ANIMATE_MAP = {3, 1, 0, 2};

public Sprite(GameView gameView, Bitmap bmp) {
    this.gameView = gameView;
    this.bmp = bmp;
    this.width = bmp.getWidth() / BMP_COL;
    this.height = bmp.getHeight() / BMP_ROWS;
}

private void Update() {
    if (x >= gameView.getWidth() - width - speedx|| x + speedx <= 0) {
    }

    if (y >= gameView.getHeight() - height - speedy || y + speedy <= 0) {
    }

    currentFrame = ++currentFrame % BMP_COL;
}

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int index = event.getActionIndex();
    int action = event.getActionMasked();
    int pointerId = event.getPointerId(index);

    synchronized (gameView.getHolder()) {
        if (this.isCollition(event.getX(), event.getY())) {
            Log.d("", "Sprite touched!");
        }

        switch (action) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                if (mVelocityTracker == null) {
                    mVelocityTracker = VelocityTracker.obtain();
                } else {
                    mVelocityTracker.clear();
                }

                xTouch = event.getX();
                yTouch = event.getY();
                Log.d("", "You clicked: " + Float.toString(xTouch) + "," + Float.toString(yTouch));
                mVelocityTracker.addMovement(event);
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                mVelocityTracker.addMovement(event);
                mVelocityTracker.computeCurrentVelocity(1000);
                Log.d("", "X velocity: " + VelocityTrackerCompat.getXVelocity(mVelocityTracker, pointerId));
                Log.d("", "Y velocity: " + VelocityTrackerCompat.getYVelocity(mVelocityTracker, pointerId));
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                mVelocityTracker.recycle();
                break;

        }
    }

    boolean ret = super.onTouchEvent(event);
    return ret;
}

public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    MotionEvent event = null;
    Update();

    int srcX = 1 * width;
    int srcY = 0 * height;

    Rect src = new Rect(srcX, srcY, srcX + width, srcY + height);
    Rect dst = new Rect(x, y, x + width, y + height);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, src, dst, null);

}

public boolean isCollition(float x2, float y2) {
    return x2 > x && x2 < x + width && y2 > y && y2 < y + height;
}
}
```

I get a logcat message each time I touch the sprite but whenever i touch the screen or swipe I get nothing. I realise that the most possible reason is me not utilizing `onTouchEvent` properly but I've tried implementing some of the things suggested in other questions but without luck.

---

**EDIT:**

It was as suggested below my game logic that was wrong here. I had the onTouchEvent in a wrong class. When I changed it into the `view` class it works perfectly:

```
public class GameView extends SurfaceView {

private Bitmap bmp;
private SurfaceHolder holder;
private GameLoop gameLoop;
private Sprite sprite;
private int x = 0;
private long lastClick;
private VelocityTracker mVelocityTracker;
private float xTouch;
private float yTouch;

public GameView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    gameLoop = new GameLoop(this);
    holder = getHolder();
    holder.addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        }

        @SuppressLint("WrongCall")
        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            gameLoop.setRunning(true);
            gameLoop.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        }

    });

    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image);
    sprite = new Sprite(this, bmp);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
    sprite.onDraw(canvas);
}

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int index = event.getActionIndex();
    int action = event.getActionMasked();
    int pointerId = event.getPointerId(index);

    synchronized (getHolder()) {
        if (sprite.isCollition(event.getX(), event.getY())) {
            Log.d("", "Sprite touched!");
        }

        switch (action) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                if (mVelocityTracker == null) {
                    mVelocityTracker = VelocityTracker.obtain();
                } else {
                    mVelocityTracker.clear();
                }

                xTouch = event.getX();
                yTouch = event.getY();
                Log.d("", "You clicked: " + Float.toString(xTouch) + "," + Float.toString(yTouch));
                mVelocityTracker.addMovement(event);
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                mVelocityTracker.addMovement(event);
                mVelocityTracker.computeCurrentVelocity(1000);
                Log.d("", "X velocity: " + VelocityTrackerCompat.getXVelocity(mVelocityTracker, pointerId));
                Log.d("", "Y velocity: " + VelocityTrackerCompat.getYVelocity(mVelocityTracker, pointerId));
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                mVelocityTracker.recycle();
                break;

        }
    }

    boolean ret = super.onTouchEvent(event);
    return ret;
}
}
```

Comment: what do you need mVelocityTracker for?

Comment: I should have stated that, I intend to use it for smooth animation so when i click the screen on x,y location the sprite has a smooth animation towards the coordinates. I'm just following the tutorial linked above but don't know if it's best practice.

Comment: then try `GestureDetector` maybe? see: `GestureDetector.OnGestureListener` and its `onFling` / `onScroll` methods, more: http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/making-interactive.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check your game logic again and handle return value manually, instead of *super.onTouchEvent(event);*

Comment: Added `return true` instead - it was a leftover from a suggestion that didn't work.
When you say check game logic, what do you mean?

Comment: check your game logic, put true, false correctly at required position as you required i.e, according to your game logic. true stands for event consumed and false for not consumed in event passing hierarchy. handle return value correctly in your case.

Comment: I get it now. The logic was flawed in my case. I had the `onTouchEvent` in the wrong class. Thanks a lot man!